# Reac js TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
class CardList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection('users')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.setState({ data: doc.data() });
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cardlist">
        {this.state.data.email
          ? this.state.data.map((data) => {
              return <div>{this.state.data.email}</div>;
            })
          : console.log('error')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function
I want to take out the emails in the Firestore and print them out, but I can't print them because of typeerror. Why is there an error?

console.log(this.state.data) result is

```js
{ createdAt: t, name: 'good', email: 'good@gmail.com', isTutor: 'off' };
{ name: 'joe', isTutor: 'on', email: 'joe@gmail.com', createdAt: t };
```

Comment: Replace your content line `{this.state.data.email}` with `{data.email}`. Since you need to refer to that specific item from data array.

Comment: `this.state.data` is not an array? It looks like multiple objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning value to your array properly, rather you should do like the code below. I've also refactored the code in render function.

```
class CardList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection('users')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, doc.data()] });
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cardlist">
        {this.state.data &&
          this.state.data.map((item) => {
            return <div>{item.email}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just in case it is not an array or we're changing its value unknowingly. It's a preventive condition so that we don't fall into such issues like you did.

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState({ data: doc.data() });` - you are not adding to the state, but replacing it with an object for each doc. And you cannot .map an object, thus the error.